# Changing timeseries column into a date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, time-series

I have a timeseries with 2 columns, the first being hours after 1 Jan 1970. In this column, a year is only 360 days, with 12 months of 30 days. I need to convert this column into a usable date so that I can analyse the other column based on month, year etc (e.g 1997-Jan-1-1 being year-month-day-hour).

I need to make an array with modulo, to convert the each row of the hours column into hour_of_day, day_of_month, year etc, so that the column is instead a year, month, day and hour. But I don't know how to do this. Appreciate it might be confusing. Any help on doing this would be very helpful.

```
Input: 233280.5 (in hours)
Output: 1997-01-01-01 (year-day-month-hour)
```

Comment: Please share a sample input and expected output in your question.

Comment: Input: 233280.5 (in hours) Output: 1997-01-01-01 (year-day-month-hour), is this sort of thing you mean?

Comment: 233280.5 hours from years that have 360 days added to 1970-01-01 should be 1997-01-01 00:30:25, no? Do you want to round to the hour?

Comment: Yes sorry, the next datapoint for example is 233281.5. So I want to round up to take that half value to be that whole hour, in this case, to be 1997-01-01-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can calculate the number of years and add it to the reference date like e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

refdate = pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')
df = pd.DataFrame({'360d_year_hours': [233280.5]})

# we calculate the number of years and fractional years as helper Series
y_frac, y = np.modf(df['360d_year_hours'] / (24*360))

# now we can calculate the new date's year:
df['datetime'] = pd.Series(refdate + DateOffset(years=i) for i in y)

# we need the days in the given year to be able to use y_frac
daysinyear = np.where(df['datetime'].dt.is_leap_year, 366, 365)

# ...so we can update the datetime and round to the hour:
df['datetime'] = (df['datetime'] + pd.to_timedelta(y_frac*daysinyear, unit='d')).dt.round('h')

# df['datetime']
# 0   1997-01-01 01:00:00
# Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you have done here, but I don't know how I would then use this with my existing dataframe. If I convert my existing dataframe to datetime will it convert it to this format? Or is there something else I need to add here?

Comment: @Delly98 not sure I get your question; you can just use the code to add a column to the existing dataframe, no? It would not modify the data you have before the calculations.

Comment: Ah right, I've got you now. So it'll just add a seperate column to my dataframe, with the date in the format here. Thank you

Comment: @Delly98 yep, and the pandas datetime data type is what you want to have to use all the [time series functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) :)